# if A>0 then b=1 else b=0

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

i would like to formulate a problem in linear programming and i cannot seem to be able to do it. The problem is: 
If A>0 then b=1
else(if A=0) then b=0,

where b is a binary variable and A>=0(integer).

Any suggestions/recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assuming**:

- A is a scalar (notation using `A` is not great)
- **A is bounded from above by constant M-1**

Constraints:

```
(1) A <= M * b
(2) b <= M * A
```

Check:

```
A = 2
    (1) b = 1
    (2) b free

A = 0
    (1) b free
    (2) b = 0

b = 1
    (1) A free 
    (2) A > 0

b = 0
    (1) A = 0
    (2) A free
```

This pretty much follows:

- the usual indicator-constraints approach like presented [here @ page 2](http://scip.zib.de/workshop2014/scip_lodi.pdf)
- Propositional calculus:

  - `x == y <-> (x -> y) & (y -> x)`

Comment: I think this may work. I am going to implement it and respond again if it works! Thank you very much for your help in any case :)

Comment: Link doesn't work

Comment: Updated [link](http://scip.zib.de/workshop2014/scip_lodi.pdf).